# Count common values from multiple list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I have multiple lists and want to find common values and count them.
for example, suppose I have the following lists.

```
l1=[1,22,63,4,5,66,7]
l2=[1,22,3,5,6,4]
l3=[1,2,3,5,66,4,70]
```

expected output:

[image]

1 is common in all list, so its ranks as 3. similarly 6 is only in one list it ranks as 1.

I tried the intersection method but it just find the common values.

Comment: Do you want the output to be a `pandas.DataFrame`?

Comment: Dataframe or dictionary both are fine.

Comment: are the number in each list unique or there are duplicates?

Comment: lists will have unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and short solution by thanks from @HenryEcker:

```
l1=[1,22,63,4,5,66,7]
l2=[1,22,3,5,6,4]
l3=[1,2,3,5,66,4,70]
lst = l1+l2+l3
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['ID']).value_counts().reset_index(name='rank')
```

Second solution: *(You can first concatenate three lists with `l1+l2+l3` then with `Counter` count and create `dict` then convert `dict` to `pandas`.)*

```
from collections import Counter

l1=[1,22,63,4,5,66,7]
l2=[1,22,3,5,6,4]
l3=[1,2,3,5,66,4,70]
lst = l1+l2+l3

df = pd.DataFrame(Counter(lst).items(), columns=['ID', 'rank'])
df = df.sort_values('rank',ascending=False)

print(df)
```

Output:

[image]

**Runtime of two solutions:** *(`%timeit` is known as line magic in iPython.(Some further magic information from the documentation [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/adrn/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Cell%20Magics.ipynb)))*

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame(Counter(lst).items(), columns=['ID', 'rank']).sort_values('rank',ascending=False)
# 952 µs ± 222 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['ID']).value_counts().reset_index(name='rank')
# 2.75 ms ± 701 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: No need for `Counter` or `sort_values` at all. Just use `value_counts`: `df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['ID']).value_counts().reset_index(name='rank')`

Comment: @MahipalSingh welcome dude, have good time :)))

Comment: @HenryEcker thanks a lot, I edit answer now. thanks a lot, I'm here for learn from you, I'm happy for your advices

Answer (score 2):

just Standard library, no pandas, using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

l1=[1,22,63,4,5,66,7]
l2=[1,22,3,5,6,4]
l3=[1,2,3,5,66,4,70]

print(Counter(chain(l1, l2, l3)))
```

output

```
Counter({1: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3, 22: 2, 66: 2, 3: 2, 63: 1, 7: 1, 6: 1, 2: 1, 70: 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a dictionary of the ranks is fairly simple:

```
common = {}
for val in set(l1+l2+l3):
    common[val] = l1.count(val) + l2.count(val) + l3.count(val)
```

where common finally equals:

```
{1: 3, 66: 2, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 1, 2: 1, 70: 1, 22: 2, 63: 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

below is a dict with the ranks (no external lib is required)

```
from collections import defaultdict

l1 = [1, 22, 63, 4, 5, 66, 7]
l2 = [1, 22, 3, 5, 6, 4]
l3 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 66, 4, 70]

data = defaultdict(int)

distinct = set()
distinct.update(l1)
distinct.update(l2)
distinct.update(l3)
print(distinct)
for v in distinct:
    for l in [l1, l2, l3]:
        if v in l:
            data[v] += 1
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 3, 66: 2, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 1, 2: 1, 70: 1, 22: 2, 63: 1})
```